# Absolute confusion! (A question about absolute *sentences*)

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I'm seriously confused about absoluteness.

A *formula* in the language of a theory $T$ is *absolute* for $T$ structures if its truth value is the same in all standard transitive models of $T$ (this may not be the most general def, but lets go with it here - it's the def. Barwise uses in *Admissible Sets and Structures*, which gave rise to this question).

There's a theorem of Feferman Kreisel to the effect of:

> if $\phi$ is absolute for $T$, then $\phi$ is $\Delta^T_1$

so far so good. But *sentences* are formulas too, and some of those will be *theorems* and hence true in all standard transitive models; but surely the above is not guaranteed for all theorems? e.g. it is a theorem that $\forall x \exists y [y = TC(x)]$, but there's no way of writing this to meet the above?

I'm sure I am *deeply* confused about something *very* simple. Please help!

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What are $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$?

Comment: $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ are closures of $\Delta_0$ formulae under unrestricted existential and universal qunatification, respectively (but not both).

Comment: So why not write $\Sigma_1,\Pi_1$ and $\Delta_1$ like everyone else. Then you can also restate this theorem "If $\phi$ Is absolute for $T$ Then $\phi$ is $\Delta_1^T$". Shorter, cleaner, and everyone's happy.

Comment: Have done. Stated that way in Barwise though; as an absolute novice, I was unsure whether or not there was a significance. In non-classical settings I suppose there would be. Not that that's the case here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm a few thousand miles from my copy of Barwise's book (cited in the question), but if I remember correctly, that book is not included in your "everyone else." In contexts where one never needs higher levels of the Lévy hierarchy, it makes sense to use $\Sigma$, $\Pi$, and $\Delta^T$ without subscripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ proves a sentence $\phi$ then $T$ proves $\phi$ is equivalent to every other sentence provable in $T$, including $(\exists x)[x=x]$ and $(\forall x)[x=x]$.  We're not "rewriting" the formula in a strong sense, we're just finding a provably equivalent formula of a certain form.

The real application of absoluteness is to sentences and formulas that are not theorems of $T$.